# How add multiple actions In URL?

Tags: url-action

How can I add more than one action to a URL? As I described in the title, I want to add more than one action to a URL. How do I do that?

As a further clarification, I define actions for some parts in an HTML file, and by setting an action, I handle the request in the php file!

Example:

```
example.com/?order=1&price=high
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i ask and get help from [my friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14552939/amir-salehi), we can use function like this to solve our problem:

```
function shapeSpace_add_var($url, $key, $value) {
    
    $url = preg_replace('/(.*)(?|&)'. $key .'=[^&]+?(&)(.*)/i', '$1$2$4', $url .'&');
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
    
    if (strpos($url, '?') === false) {
        return ($url .'?'. $key .'='. $value);
    } else {
        return ($url .'&'. $key .'='. $value);
    }
}
```

example:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/whatever/?hello=world';

shapeSpace_add_var($url, 'goodbye', 'nightclub');
```

Result:

```
http://example.com/whatever/?hello=world&goodbye=nightclub
```